# How to get the package name of current launcher in android?

Tags: android

I want to get the package name of the current launcher that I have currently installed. I tried using the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344824/how-can-i-get-the-package-name-of-the-current-launcher-in-android-2-3-and-above

but it gives the result as "android". I want the complete launcher name .

[image: List Of Launchers]

I want the list of launchers installed and the current launcher selected

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, you don't need the package name. You only need to create an implicit intent, not an explicit one.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Please elaborate your answer..

Comment: I was responding to your post before you edited it. Are you trying to make your own launcher? Are you trying to make your own chooser of launchers? What is your end goal?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk My end Goal is to launch a particular service only when I'm at my home screen. Their may be any 3rd party launcher being installed

Answer (score 31):

you can get current launcher package name using below code:

```
PackageManager localPackageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
String str = localPackageManager
        .resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)
        .activityInfo
        .packageName;
Log.e("Current launcher Package Name:", str);
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Thanks.

Comment: its working but when press home key in oneplus device it cant get launcher package name

Answer (score 2):

as Fede's answer in [Get a list of every launcher in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175821/get-a-list-of-every-launcher-in-android)

get a list of all installed launchers.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
List<ResolveInfo> lst = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (!lst.isEmpty()) {
   for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : lst) {
        Log.d("Test", "New Launcher Found: " + resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not ensure that the first result is the one currently in use (as the question specifically requests) and actually makes no attempt to determine the one in use at all.

Answer (score 2):

Following code works perfectly to get the current launcher app package name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
String currentLauncherName= resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
Log.d("Current Launcher: ", currentLauncherName);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [package visibility changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility) introduced in Android 11, it is now necessary to add a [queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) element in your application's manifest file as below before you can query one of the [PackageManager.resolveActivity(intent:flags:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#resolveActivity(android.content.Intent,%20int)), [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent:flags:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) etc methods for the home (a.k.a. launcher) activities that are installed on the device:

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

If this [queries](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element) element is omitted from your application's manifest, then the device will report the `com.android.settings.FallbackHome` activity as the one and only home activity installed on the device.

For guidance on how to call on the [PackageManager.resolveActivity(intent:flags:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#resolveActivity(android.content.Intent,%20int)), [PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent:flags:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) etc methods, see the other answers in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this：

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
val resolveInfo: ResolveInfo = context.packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY)?: return null
val currentLauncherPackageName: String = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
val currentLauncherClassName: String = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name
```

Two boundary cases:

Result 1: android (This happens when the system has multiple launcher applications, but the user does not make the default selection)

Result 2: The corresponding package name.