# Get name of the application from package name - xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

im developing xamarin.android app.I need to get title name of the application from package name.

ex :

- package name- com.google.android.gm
- title name - Gmail

tried this code. this give me unhanded exception

```
 string appName = pm.GetApplicationLabel(pm.GetApplicationInfo("com.google.android.gm", PackageInfoFlags.MetaData));
```

exception -

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

03-14 10:54:58.122 I/zygote64(15547): Thread[3,tid=15553,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x73480c0400,peer=0x1ca00020,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
03-14 10:54:58.123 I/zygote64(15547): 
03-14 10:54:58.258 I/zygote64(15547): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Add the exception details here.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: This forum link might help you: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22007/how-do-i-get-the-applicationname-in-code

Comment: no that code for get same app name. i need another app name

Comment: I assume pm is null.

Comment: If you are looking for Activities which has launcher, then you can use this Java code and convert to C#, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175821/get-a-list-of-every-launcher-in-android

Comment: public PackageManager pm; is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the reason. here is the complete code.

```
string appName = PackageManager.GetApplicationLabel(PackageManager.GetApplicationInfo("com.google.android.gm", PackageInfoFlags.MetaData));
```

this returns "Gmail"